# How to a get hosname of MongoDB replicaset on SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm new to MogoDB.

Trying to get a hostname of MongoDB on SpringBoot aplication.
I want to know which mongodb node the spring boot application has connected to, among replicaset(node1~3).

Briefly say, hostname return required when requesting to springboot REST api by excuting mongodb query below.

db.hostInfo().system.hostname;

------I did this in mysql case(See below)---------------

```
package com.deploy.sometest.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HostNameService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public String getHostName() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("**select @@hostname**", String.class);


    }
}
```

Sample code or "how to" to solve my problem.

Comment: You should be using MongoTemplate if you are using MongoDB + SpringJPA.   However I do not think you can get which replica it is currently connecting to.  Monitor the logs an it might tell you.   You can also investigate MongoClient and see if that can help

Comment: Actually, I'm developing an application for HA failover test, MariaDB and MongoDB. I'd better see MongoDB logs, as following  your advisory Thank you so much.pnfor hour help.